# Getting failure in Calculate Field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

After today's SW update I keep getting this failure, not sure why, but I am thinking it's the expression. I have no idea how to change the expression to something that makes sense if that's the issue.

This task seems to just modify one table, "Tracts", but the part of the expression that says "COUNT_Visit_Date" is part of a separate table called "Visit_Dates_ByTract". Both fields in both tables are correctly entered and valid.

[image: Task box]

[image: Error Details]

Comment: Please always provide errors as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: Ok, sorry, but what is formatted text?

Comment: For an error message, highlight the text and click the double quotes button of the editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can only calculate values based on the fields in a second table if that second table is joined onto the one where you want to make the calculations.

Comment: So join the tables first and then calculate?